# Converting NA values in a dataframe to an arbitrary integer with for loop and if statement

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I want to convert my NA values in below dataframe `d1` to an integer value like 13 but it seems that my `for` loop and `if` statement wouldn't work.
I would appreciate if anyone could help me.

```
L3 <- LETTERS[1:3]
fac <- sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10, fac = fac)

d1 <- d
d1$x[1:3] <- NA
d1$y[4:6] <- NA
d1$fac[7:10] <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(d1)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(d1)){
    if (is.na(d1[i,j]) == TRUE) {
      (d1[i,j]) == 13
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The easy way would be to do `d1[is.na(d1)] <- 13`. The main issue with your `for`:  Use `d1[i,j] <- 13` instead of `(d1[i,j]) == 13`. The latter is a logical condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably due to typo.

```r
L3 <- LETTERS[1:3]
fac <- sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10, fac = fac)
d1 <- d
d1$x[1:3] <- NA
d1$y[4:6] <- NA
d1$fac[7:10] <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(d1)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(d1)){
    if (is.na(d1[i,j])) {
      d1[i,j] <-  13
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
d1
#>     x  y fac
#> 1  13  1   A
#> 2  13  2   B
#> 3  13  3   C
#> 4   1 13   B
#> 5   1 13   A
#> 6   1 13   B
#> 7   1  7  13
#> 8   1  8  13
#> 9   1  9  13
#> 10  1 10  13
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>